# default height in <div>

Tags: css, html

i have two div tag like this:

```
<div class="cl1">
  <div class="cl2">
    <canvas id="testcanvas"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

div.cl1 has width and height in css

```
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
```

div.cl2 has not, i guess it will use default width and height.

but when i use this

```
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
```

in canvas#testcanvas its height is not 100% of div.cl1, it's just about 30%;like this

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA8Ep.png)

> green is canvas#testcanvas and div.cl2
>   blue is div.cl1;

so how a div tag calculate default height.

and also when i Removed `<!DOCTYPE html>`, in canvas#testcanvas its height is 100% div.cl1, i thought there are different behavior i don't know

Comment: put your code properly (or) shom me your output

Answer (score 0):

The width & height of HTML5 canvas elements should be set explicitly, as this defines the area of the rendering context. E.G. ...

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

... will give you a full page canvas for example.

The CSS width/height is a display property only, and if no width/height is set on a canvas it resolves to it's default size for that device/browser.  Some additional resizing methods to cover orientation changes may be needed on mobile devices.

Comment: in fact, when use  
    `width: 100%; `
    `height: 100%;`
for both div.cl1 and div.cl2;  
i truly get a full page canvas.
I want to know when i not use 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
for div.cl2, why i get a about 30% canvas, it shows the same thing in both chrome and firefox.

Comment: Probably it give div.cl2 some default Attributes, if it has not Attributes.
I want to know how it works.

Comment: @zstiu The height of HTML DIVs 'flow' according to their content.  If you specify the canvas dimension the DIV (.cl2) it sits inside should flow accordingly.  [See Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The width and height relative to the parent dom object of itself.

The first one is 's height and then the ...

So if you are using height:100%; you have to set heights of html,body and any other container element of yours.